# Ordinary Double Point Characterization

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, algebraic-curves

I'm reading Qing Liu's Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves in an attempt to understand Artin-Winters' proof of Deligne-Mumford's semi-stable reduction theorem. I'm having a bit of trouble understanding the algebraic characterization of ordinary double points. In particular, letting $X$ be a reduced curve over an algebraically closed field $k$, and letting $\pi:X'\to X$ be the normalization morphism, we call a closed point $x\in X$ an ordinary double point if $\pi^{-1}(x)$ consists of 2 points, and we have$$\dim_k\left(\mathcal{O}'_{X,x}/\mathcal{O}_{X,x}\right) = [k(x):k] = 1$$where $\mathcal{O}'_{X,x}$ is the integral closure of $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ in $\operatorname{Frac}(\mathcal{O}_{X,x})$. I'm having trouble understanding what the dimension of the quotient $\mathcal{O}'_{X,x}/\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ as a $k$-vector space means (geometrically, say) and, in particular, what it means for it to be 1. Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The dimension of $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}'/\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ is "how many" extra functions you need to be able to tell the germs of $X'$ through the two points $x_1,x_2$ on the normalization living above $x$ apart. As the normalization map is given by [some undue gluing of subvarieties and tangent spaces](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/109395/is-there-a-geometric-intuition-underlying-the-notion-of-normal-varieties), it measures how much stuff got glued together. In the case of an ordinary double point, the answer is that two points got glued together but none of their tangent directions - the function that gets added to form the integral closure is one which distinguishes the points $x_1$ and $x_2$.

It may also be helpful to hear a little bit about other better definition of a node (aka ordinary double point). Vakil and the Stacks Project define a node (at least in the algebraically closed case) to be a singular point on a curve which has $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}^\wedge\cong k[[x,y]]/(xy)$ as topological rings. In my opinion, this is much clearer to understand. It turns out that your definition in terms of the number of preimages and $\delta=\dim \mathcal{O}_{X,x}'/\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ is equivalent to this - the main ingredient is [Stacks 0C3W](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0C3W) saying that it doesn't matter where we compute $\delta$ - the local ring, the strict henselization, or the completion will all give the same result.